# Getting description from jQuery whatweather

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have setup the jQuery plugin [WhatWeather](http://getkode.be/whatweather/whatweather-documentation/) and its working fine but have a little problem.

When i get the weather data i get this txt file.

```
{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "100", "humidity": "100", "localObsDateTime": "2013-12-08 02:23 PM", "observation_time": "01:23 PM", "precipMM": "4.3", "pressure": "1008", "temp_C": "7", "temp_F": "45", "visibility": "7", "weatherCode": "296",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Light rain" } .....] }}
```

To get data showed on my page i use "currentCondition.cloudcover" and then i get the cloudcover 100, but i can't get the weather description i have tried "currentCondition.weatherDesc" and then i get the output "Object : Object". and not "Light rain" how do I get the value "Light Rain" from the txt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wheatherDesc` is an array of an object itself so try `currentCondition.weatherDesc[0].value`

So overall:

```
data.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value
```